# What is the Unix/Linux equivalent of Registered I/O?

Tags: linux, unix, network-programming, winsock

Windows 8 and Server 2012 sport [RIO](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh997032.aspx), which allows you to pre-register I/O buffers once and then just use those same buffers repeatedly, avoiding the otherwise (apparently) necessary per-I/O-op buffer checks.

RIO also allows completion operations such as polling to be done entirely in user-mode, without making system calls.

(How) is this possible with Linux/Unix?

Comment: Describe the thing you are actually trying to accomplish.  There is probably a perfectly rational way to do it in Linux.

Comment: epoll maybe like the above comment no idea what you are tying to do.

Comment: There is an NI-RIO Driver for Linux... You may try to have a look at http://rapidio.org/

Comment: There was a fair bit of ambiguity I wasn't sure what you were after. Did you want to send packets as fast as possible or recieve packets or both? Will you be dealing with multiple clients? Reading about netmap it creates a FD you still need to select/poll on so you may need to consider these things.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I just added the specific use-case, although I was also interested generally if what RIO does is possible in Linux. And it is, as my own answer shows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting with Linux Kernel 5.1 there is finally proper support with [io_uring](https://kernel.dk/io_uring.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of this. This looks great - and includes support for writing/reading without any system calls!

Answer (score 1):

It seems [netmap](http://info.iet.unipi.it/%7Eluigi/netmap/) is that - and [more](http://info.iet.unipi.it/%7Eluigi/papers/20120503-netmap-atc12.pdf):

> In building netmap, we identified and successfully reduced or
> removed three main packet processing costs:
>
> 1. per-packet dynamic memory allocations, removed by **preallocating resources**
> 2. system call overheads, amortized over large batches
> 3. and memory copies, eliminated by sharing buffers and metadata between kernel and userspace, while still protecting access to device
>    registers and other kernel memory areas